# What should I do about "302 Found" exceptions when downloading with Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy

I am trying to download a file to a string:

```
function FetchUrl(const url: string): string;
var
 idhttp : TIdHTTP;
begin
  idhttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    Result := idhttp.Get(url);
  finally
    idhttp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

What is wrong with this code? I get an exception: HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Comment: If I remember correctly, there's an option in TIdHTTP that allows you to set "AllowRedirects" or something like that, then it will automatically redirect, except of course, if there's some magic done using javascript...

Comment: The correct property name is `HandleRedirects`.

Comment: I get this same exception while downloading from an https location, but only when there's a proxy in the middle. Shouldn't https traffic pass "transparently" thru a proxy? Why should I get redirected? I had kept HandleRedirects to FALSE on purpose...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the `TIdHTTP.HandleRedirects` property to True. It is False by default.

```
function FetchUrl(const url: string): string; 
var 
 idhttp : TIdHTTP; 
begin 
  idhttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil); 
  try 
    idhttp.HandleRedirects := True;
    Result := idhttp.Get(url); 
  finally 
    idhttp.Free; 
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP response code 302 means the remote server wants to redirect you to another URL, which is specified in the Location header of the response.  You need to do something special to look at the Location header and go to that URL.  Maybe your http library has an option to do this automatically, so check the documentation.